# Tomcat is automatically shutting down

Tags: java, debian, tomcat7, containers

I have installed Tomcat 7 with Java 7 on a debian box.  It has 512 MB of RAM.  I run tomcat out of the box, I have installed nothing, and it is consistently shutting down by itself.  I am not even browsing the Tomcat landing page.

As you can see, it is running perfectly normal and then all of a sudden it stops:

```
Jul 21, 2013 6:11:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 21, 2013 6:11:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1063 ms
Jul 21, 2013 8:22:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 21, 2013 8:22:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 21, 2013 8:22:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
```

It just mysteriously stops.  What can it be?  I know the Tomcat distribution and the Java distribution are good because I downloaded them from the Tomcat site and Oracle, and FTP'd them over to my server.

There are no other errors in any other tomcat log files.  Is is a permissions thing?  Memory issue?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Does it not have any logs that you can inspect? Firewall is ok? Check other system logs as well. Monitor memory usage with top or htop. It's best to install apps via apt-get when available.

Answer (score 0):

I think a memory issue would show up in the log. I would simply reinstall Tomcat and check if it's still buggy.

Comment: Hi @Rápli András, I tried this with 2 different tomcat binaries.  Once, when I downloaded it via the WGET command in Debian and the 2nd time when I upload it myself.  I think there is some server related issue.  I've turned on logging in tomcat to ALL to catch any errors.